# NoMethodError in Discussions#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Below is code extract from my file `app/views/discussions/show.html.erb` where line 16 raised this error:

> ```
> undefined method `markdown' for #<#<Class:0x000000000c94e0d8>:0x000000000c94c6e8>
> ```

```html
s<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-8">
    <h1 class="title is-2 has-text-grey discussion-title"><%= @discussion.title %></h1>
    <h3 class="subtitle is-5 has-text-grey-lighter">by <%= @discussion.user.username %> in <%= link_to @discussion.channel.channel, @discussion.channel %></h3>
    <div class="level">
      <div class="level-left"></div>
      <div class="level-right">
        <% if  discussion_url(@discussion) %>
        <div class="buttons">
            <%= link_to 'Edit Discussion', edit_discussion_path(@discussion), class:'button'%>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', discussion_path(@discussion), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Delete discussion?" }, class:'button' %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"><%= markdown (@discussion.content) %></div>
    <!--                     ^^^^^^^^                            -->

    <h2 class="subtitle is-5 has-text-grey"><%= @discussion.replies.count %> Replies</h2>

    <div id="discussion-replies">
      <%= render @discussion.replies %>
    </div>

    <hr/>

    <h3 class="subtitle is-3 has-text-grey">Leave a reply</h3>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= render 'replies/form' %>
    <% else %>
    <p>To reply you need to <%= link_to 'login', new_user_session_path %>. Don't have an account?
      <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %> for one.</p>
    <% end %>

  </div>

    <%= render 'sidebar' %>

</div>
```

cant view reply or comment section

Comment: Which gem did you use?

Comment: Rails doesn't offer a `markdown` method by default. So @SamyKacimi assumes that you are using some gem or custom code to get things working.

Comment: i used 'redcarpet', '~> 3.5' , and looking at the answer below looks like i have to write my own helper

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't include a `markdown` method. You'll have to use a gem, write something yourself or a combination of the two. You could for example use the [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) gem, or one of the other [markup processor gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/markup_processors).

Then write your own helper using this using this gem.

```
# app/helpers/markdown_helper.rb
module MarkdownHelper
  MARKDOWN = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)

  def markdown(markdown_string)
    MARKDOWN.render(markdown_string).html_safe
  end
end
```

For usage and possible render configurations checkout out the [redcarpet documentation](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#and-its-like-really-simple-to-use).

With this helper present you can simply do the following in the view:

```
<%= markdown(@discussion.content) %>
```

Comment: i did use 'redcarpet', '~> 3.5'  but didn't write any helper, thanks a lot,will let u know if any thing happens

Comment: You don't have to use a helper, but writing `<%= raw Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML).render(@discussion.content) %>` might be a bit cumbersome, and that's with the use of default options. If you want to change any render options the line is only getting longer.